# Compare two datetimes and get day difference

Tags: python

I have an array of dates. I am comparing the objects of the array (B) to a control (A). How do I check if B's age is 10 days when compared to A? Ideally, I would like to be able to declare a variable as the difference in days. Thanks.

Comment: [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 8):

This Python code template will compute the difference in days:

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 1)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5)
diff = d2 - d1
print diff.days
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference of two `datetime.datetime` objects is a `datetime.timedelta` object. Its `.days` attribute gives you its length in days.